# How to find the records from the object array of object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb, collection name: person

```
[
  {
    name:"John",
    pens:[
      {color:"blue", price:1},
      {color:"black",price:2},
      {color:"black", price:3},
      {color:"red", price:2}
    ]
  },
  {
    name:"Mary",
    pens:[
      {color:"green", price:3},
      {color:"black",price:2},
      {color:"blue", price:1},
      {color:"red", price:2}
    ]
  },
  {
    name:"Tom",
    pens:[
      {color:"black", price:1},
      {color:"black",price:4},
      {color:"blue", price:1},
      {color:"green", price:3}
    ]
  }
]
```

First question: 
I would like to find out all black pens of "John" and hope the result is like this

```
[
  {color:"black", price:2},
  {color:"black, price:3"}
]
```

However, my query

```
db.person.find({name:"John"},{pens:{$elemMatch:{color:"black"}}})
```

It only shows the first record. How do I get the records in the subarray?

```
[
  {color:black,price:2}
]
```

The second question:
I would like to find out how many black pens John has.

```
db.person.count({name:"John"},{pens:{$elemMatch:{color:"black"}}})
```

It shows 1 but the correct number is 2. 
How do I get the correct count in the subarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `$elemMatch` operator project the **first** matching element from an array based on a condition.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

**Workaround:** Perform MongoDB aggregation. With `$filter` operator we take black color pens.

```
db.person.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "John"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      pens: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$pens",
          as: "pens",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$pens.color",
              "black"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$pens"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$pens"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dVx3PVEUj_Z) | [Count black pens](https://mongoplayground.net/p/svnF_suF6Gm)